# How do I use a Nikon D3100 and sync cord with Novatron lights?

Tags: lighting, strobes

Just bought the Novatron V400D light set and I can't seem to connect the sync cord to my Nikon D3100. Is there a sync cord connection on the camera? What are my next best options please??

Answer (score 1):

**No, the D3100**, as an entry-level camera **does not have a sync connector**. You typically have to go up to the prosumer-level cameras to have a PC (Prontor-Compur) port on a camera for off-camera flash sync.  All you need to create a sync connection, however, is **[a hotshoe adapter](http://www.flashzebra.com/hotshoes-shoes/camera-hotshoes.shtml)**.  When purchasing, you will want to be certain whether it's an adapter that can be used on the camera or the flash (or both)--not all adapters work in both directions. The most typical sync connections are PC, or 3.5mm (aka 1/8") minijack/phone connectors (some do  both).

Other, less common, sync connectors are HH (household--like a US two-pronged plug into a power socket), or 6.35mm (aka "1/4") phone connectors.  Your Novatron uses HH, so you may end up having to get a [3.5mm](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/613977-REG/Impact_9031510_Mini_3_5_mm_to.html) or [PC-to-household](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=PC%20to%20HH&N=0&InitialSearch=yes&sts=ma&Top%20Nav-Search=) adapter as well. On the plus side, all you'll need for a sync cable is a regular two-prong power extension cord.

Another less-adpater-riddled solution is to use simple **radio triggers**. Many of them connect directly to camera hotshoes, and have PC sync or 3.5mm or 2.5mm phone connector output ports, so you just put the transmitter on the camera hotshoe, and then find the correct cable/adapters to connect a receiver to the lights.

Understand, however, that all of these connections are manual-only and can only communicate the "fire" signal.  Power levels have to be set directly on the lights.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a hot shoe PC adapter for your camera. They are readily available almost anywhere, under several brand names, and relatively cheap.

Alternatively, and more normally these days, you can also get a radio trigger set. The transmitter will fit into the hot shoe of your camera, and the receiver will usually have a connector for a PC sync cord, or an adapter cord that you can plug directly into your Novatron pack. Getting rid of something that's easy to trip over and restricts your freedom of movement is a good thing, and simple "fire only" trigger sets can also be relatively cheap (or you can go expensive with something like PocketWizard).